# Software to simulate the reflection of sub-wavelength sized features

Tags: optics, visible-light, resource-recommendations, reflection, software

I want to simulate the reflection of a 2D array of sub-wavelength sized features. I would like to simulate the reflection of the microstructures.

I am looking for a free software which would enable me to do such such simulation.

Maybe a RCWA code... but I would be nice, if it is user friendly or at least has some decent tutorials.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a software request and not about physics. [softwarerecs.se] might be better suited for this question, however.